# Where to download nsrdb weather data

Tags: weather, pvlib

I want to explore PVLib on nsrdb datasets, but I can't figure out where to download (or access) them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSRDB data can be downloaded manually from the [NSRDB Viewer](https://maps.nrel.gov/nsrdb-viewer/), or programmatically through their [API](https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/solar/nsrdb/) using [pvlib.iotools.get_psm3](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.iotools.get_psm3.html).